# Being able to click on a question score to see number of up & down-votes - is this dependent on user's reputation?

Tags: support, questions, reputation, voting

This is a functionality I've seen on other SE sites but I'm sure when I was first on music.se, it wasn't working. However I tried today and now it is. Is that because you need a certain amount of rep to see the separate up/down vote counts - if so where is this documented?

Comment: Generally, if you want to see what you are able to do (or will be) on this site, you should check out the [Privileges](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct: view vote counts is part of the Established User privilege.

https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

On our site this is set to 750 for beta, but once graduation is complete it should revert to the standard 1,000.